# What's the difference between the Rahn algorithm and the Forte algorithm?

Tags: set-theory

What is the **difference** between the two algorithms (**Rahn** and **Forte**). *Would* there be a reason to use the **Rahn** algorithm instead of the **Forte** algorithm or *vice versa?*